# Boilerplate Ignite for Android using React Native on a Linux Platform

Tags: android, react-native, boilerplate

I am trying to integrate Boilerplate for Android using React Native on Ubuntu 16.04 but i don't know where to start and what to do next .

So far I did the steps below :

1)Install React-Native on Linux Platform
1.  Install NodeJs and npm:

```
    $sudo apt install curl 
    $curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash –
    $sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

2. Check the version of nodejs:

> $node -v

Or

> $nodejs -v

3. Check the version of npm:

> ```
> $npm -v
> ```

4. Install the create-react-native-app:

> $sudo npm install -g create-react-native-app

5. Create the first project:

> $create-react-native-app MyFirstProject

6. Move to the project directory using:

> $cd MyFirstProject/

7. Using the next command, the development server will start:

> $npm start

2)I installed Java:

```
$sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

$sudo apt-get update
$sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
$sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

3)I installed Android : 
Downloaded “All Android Studio Packages” archive from:
[https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html](http://Download%20%E2%80%9CAll%20Android%20Studio%20Packages%E2%80%9D%20archive%20from:%20https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

Extract the archive file into an appropriate location:

```
$sudo unzip android-studio-ide-141.2178183-linux.zip -d /opt
```

Lunch Android:

```
$./studio.sh.
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Swagger doesn't have anything to do with Android. It's just a documentation html page for a REST API. How did you "somehow find" it? Why do you think you need it?

Comment: I am trying to integrate Boilerplate for Android using React Native on a Linux Platform (and to realize an Android application) and someone gave me an hint about installing swagger and to try to make a connection between Android and Swagger editor . I might have understood wrong and maybe that person somehow did not understood what i needed to do and the hint was for no good .

Comment: Maybe I should edit my question or delete it, but I don t know exactly what to search for or how to ask exactly :(

Comment: React Native does not need Swagger either. I'm very confused

Comment: Isn't there a like `react-native-create-app` function that sets up a project for you? https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app

Comment: React -Native doesn't work with  android on Ubuntu, and I was looking for something else to make it work .

Comment: NPM and Java and Android Studio all work on Ubuntu. I'm still not understanding what you've done so far and what errors specifically you're having

Comment: Yes there is. I have created a project

Comment: https://gist.github.com/platonish/f913e8a691ae811524f47bfb7710437b

Comment: Thank you, I will try the links you gave me and came back with an answer :)

Comment: In the meantime, I suggest you edit your question to explain what you've tried so far in order to create a project and run an app that doesn't involve Swagger

Comment: OK, I will do that, thank you again .

Comment: Hope this time I made myself more clear. I deteled everything I wrote about swagger since was off topic with my problem. Thank you or making that clear :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next steps would be to open the Android SDK Manager within Studio and install the API version you're targeting and any System images you'll like to run in order to get an emulator (assuming you're not using a physical device)

You'll also need to set `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable so React knows where the Android build tools are

For example, edit your bash profile

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk 
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools 
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Your SDK would be under /opt, possibly

Eventually, run your code with `react-native run-android`